# Is RavenDb performance better in comparison to relational databases?

Tags: nosql, relational-database, ravendb

What are the factors which make RavenDb (as an example of NoSQL document database) more efficient in comparison to relational databases?

I know two factors:

1. All queries are executed on indexes. But you can do it in RDBMS
2. Indexes are updated on background threads (causing
   missynchronization). Yep, it is a good point but I doubt it is very
   significant.

Actually I thought the biggest performance boost is absense of joins but looks like Multi Maps / Reduce Index is pretty similar to join.

So what factors do make RavenDb more efficient?

Comment: RavenDB does _different things_ from RDBMSs. You can't compare a document database to a relational one like that.

Comment: @Oded, a lot of people use RavenDb and relation databases for solving pretty similar tasks. So in my opinion we can and should compare them

Comment: Then why not ask about CoucheDB? Or MongoDB? Cassandra?

Comment: @Oded, because they have a lot of differences and I am playing with RavenDb now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Idsa,
There are several reasons why you would typically see a RavenDB application much faster than a Relational DB application.

a) As Daniel mentioned, the difference in data modeling is significant. It means that you can load the data in a much cheaper way.

b) You always query on indexes. That is important, because it means that the query plan for RavenDB is always an INDEX_SEEK. Sure, you can *try* doing that using RDBMS, but in many cases, you don't always hit an index. In particular, you usually have to do a lot more work to get there, and then you have to use joins and other stuff to get the data out, which again complicates the query plan.

c) RavenDB will work behind the scenes to optimize itself on your behalf. The more you use it, the more it will optimize itself to your usage pattern.

d) You never do any computation whatsoever during the queries. That is critical, because it means that things like aggregation queries, for example, are already precomputed, so they are *really* cheap.

Comment: Thank you, great answer! Just wanted to clarify how significantly do multi map / reduce indexes slow RavenDb performance. If I got it right they are pretty similar to relational joins

Comment: Idsa,there isn't a perf difference here worth talking about.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think one can say that RavenDB is generally faster in comparison with a relational database. It certainly depends on what kind of data-operations you want to do within your application.

The one reason why *most* applications are faster is that RavenDB is equally fast both on the read and the write side because indexes are updated asynchronously. However, this comes with the cost of eventual consistency. While that will be ok for most applications it is not priceless.

The other heavy-weight reason is more about document databases in general. A single document in RavenDB (and others as well) can contain a complete object graph and also denormalized references, thus eliminating many request to the database. In most scenarios it's not the database itself that makes an application slow but more often an excessive number of requests sent to the database server (consider network latency + overhead). Document databases are well suited for stateless applications like web-applications where a single view displays information of a whole object graph (think about an order, along with all the items, customers information, billing information, etc.).